# What would trigger "OAuthException: (#200) User cannot access this application"?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-opengraph

**What would trigger "OAuthException: (#200) User cannot access this application"?**
I cannot find any information on this particular error.  There are many posts related to a similar error ("*(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"*), but nothing related to the user not being able to **access** the application...

The problem surfaced in just the last couple of days.  Prior to that, the same action by the same user would result in an open graph post...  It appears the error isn't isolated to a single user.  Several users have experienced it.  I would greatly appreciate any help on this matter.  Thank you.

Comment: did you get any solution for this.
i get this while trying to post picture via graph api of fb from mobile

Comment: I had the same issue too, any solution guys?